# URL Comparison and domain jumping

Tags: c#, url, web

I have a website that has seperate domains but runs on the same the server. They have seperate logins and are basically seperate entities even though they use the same pages with varying artwork controlled by javascript.

What I am basically looking for now is a way to control "Domain Jumping". Thus I want to have a way to check the current url and the previous url and then compare domains. If the domains differ then the person would be redirected to the previous page or login page of the previous url.

I tried to do this with the "SESSION" variable but I can't seem to get the logic right.

Has anyone got an example they could show me?

Ok the brain is finally waking up. What i've done is created 2 session variables, 1 for the current domain and 1 for the previous domain. Then on each page I compare the current and previous domains. If they don't match I redirect the user back to the previous domains logon page and if they do match I set the previous domain equal the current domain.

Does this seem like a robust solution or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!!

Comment: So you want to do this on MVP or MVC?

Comment: It's done in asp.net c#

Answer (score 0):

I would implement this using the HTTP referrer ("referer") header field. Check the URL in the header and if it differs from your current domain, redirect back to where the user came from (alternatively to your login page).

Comment: browsers do not necessarily always send a referrer when doing a meta refresh. I also understand that if they access the website directly then no referrer will be sent. So I don't think this will work.

Comment: True, I didn't check how browsers are implementing meta refresh. Ok, then I would say that you might need to share sessions across multiple applications.

Comment: Yeah that is what I thought too. I am just battling with the logic of how it will work... I can't think of how to compare the previous domain with the current one with out overwriting the previous domain every time.